# Inner content and scroll bar cut off by height of sibling element when parent element height set with vh

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sidebar that is a fixed percentage of the view port.  Inside the sidebar, I'd like an element that is fixed to the top while the rest of content scrolls if it take up more vertical space than the sidebar height.

In this example, the `h1` element remains at the top of the parent element while the rest of the content, `.inner` can be scrolled.  The content and scroll bar inside `.inner` is cut off by the height of the `h1` element.

How can I display the all the content and scroll bar?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body: {
  height: 100vh; 
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'left right';
    justify-content: space-around;
    grid-gap: 12px;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.right {
  gird-area: right
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  height: 90vh; 
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="side">
      <div class="outer">
        <h1>other content</h1>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>1</p>
          <p>2</p>
          <p>3</p>
          <p>4</p>
          <p>5</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid setting explicit heights on things whenever possible. That tends to bite you. Set the rules for your flex layout and let it do its thing. If you need whitespace somewhere, keep things simple and add it to the box's contents, not the box itself. By separating the concerns of layout and content, you make it easier to pluck out one bit of content and replace it without getting into the CSS for your layout.

Scroll into the CSS for hints.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body: {
  height: 100vh; 
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'left right';
    justify-content: space-around;
    grid-gap: 12px;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.right {
  gird-area: right
}

.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  height: 90vh; 
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex; /* <--------------- change */
  flex-direction: column; /* <--------------- add */
}

.inner {
  /* height: 100%; <--------------- remove */
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  flex: 0 0; /* <--------------- change */
  background: lightgrey;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="side">
      <div class="outer">
        <h1>other content</h1>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>1</p>
          <p>2</p>
          <p>3</p>
          <p>4</p>
          <p>5</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>      
</div>
```